# OnCommand Not Firing After OnClientClick return confirm

Tags: c#, asp.net, events, onclientclick

I have this delete function that was working perfectly fine. Wanted to add a confirmation right before the user decides to delete it, but now my delete won't work after the user returns OK from the confirmation box.

HTML:

```
<div>
    <asp:Button ID="btnDelete" UseSubmitBehavior="false" runat="server" Text="Remove" 
        CssClass="appdl" CommandName="Remove" OnCommand="AppsList_ItemCommand" 
        OnClientClick="return confirm('Are you certain you want to delete?');"
        CommandArgument='<%# Eval("ID") %>' />
</div>
```

As you can see in the HTML above, I'm using OnCommand to perform the delete function. After I added in OnClientClick, OnCommand seems to stop firing, even after I click OK. Not really sure what's wrong. Any pointer would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Your `Command` was overriden by javascript onClientClick. (Not sure about this)

Comment: @Zenvo, was the OnCommand event getting fire before specifying the OnClientClick?

Comment: nope, I have the OnCommand removing the item from the listview, but when I click btnDelete, all I get was the confirmation box, nothing was deleted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

remove `UseSubmitBehavior="false"` from your mark up and the try

Comment: Need to disable event validation though

Answer (score 1):

```
function conformbox()
{
var con=confirm("Are you sure want to delete?");
if(con==true)
{
return true;
}
else
{
return false;}
}
```

-------------//*//----------------

```
<asp:Button ID="deleteBtn" runat="server" Text="Delete User" OnClientClick="return         
conformbox();" /><br />
```

check the return values (true or false)

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
<div>
    <span onclick="return confirm('Are you certain you want to delete?');">
       <asp:Button ID="btnDelete" UseSubmitBehavior="false" runat="server" Text="Remove" 
            CssClass="appdl" CommandName="Remove" OnCommand="AppsList_ItemCommand"         
            CommandArgument='<%# Eval("ID") %>' />
      </span>
<div/>
```

Comment: this deleted the file even if I pressed Cancel

Comment: Use same code but small change, use OnClick instead of OnCommand Or Remove UseSubmitBehavior="false"
attribute.